# Derivation of CNN math equations in Matrix format

Tags: neural-network, convolution

I've gone through jefkine's website and Jae Seo's articles to get a hold of math behind the famous CNN architecture. Although I understand it in theory, I'm unable to implement in matrix format or to put it straight...  In numpy format. After digging through internet like a broken web scraper, I could only understand FC ANN after Andrew Ng tutorial and this,  sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/. Can someone please help me understand CNN architecture in similar way? 
I'm expecting downvotes and closed as off topic by admins for being naive and dumb. If that's the price I gotta pay to learn...  So be it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain to you exactly what you want. However, if you got in [this link](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2018/assignment2/) and work on Q4, maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I found this. https://github.com/MahanFathi/CS231/blob/master/assignment2/cs231n/layers.py
I don't get it though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNb2fEVKeEo&list=PLC1qU-LWwrF64f4QKQT-Vg5Wr4qEE1Zxk&index=5 doesn't help either because they don't explain how it all works.

Comment: https://medium.com/@2017csm1006/forward-and-backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-network-4dfa96d7b37e is more along the lines of what I want. I need maxpool version of it too.

Comment: I am a poor coder. I understand that in CNN (LeNet), the equations go like this.

Fwd Propagation :
Output_of_layer = Convolution(Image,Filter)
Back Propagation :
error_filter = Convolution(Image, error_from_prev_layer)
error_image = Full_Convolution(error_from_prev_layer, rot180(Filter))

How do I code this without numpy in python?
How do I scale it up to multiple kernels and multiple channels (RGB)?

Comment: I just want to get into the math of it, architecture of it, the inherent layer pattern applied there and not just fill a template provided by Stanford. I hope you understand my voice.